# Can't access CFSolutionStorefrontSite_CatalogWebService/CatalogWebService

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-connect

I am setting up commerce server site. But I can't access CSServices site. I followed all steps mentioned at commercesdn site:

- Create a folder named C:\inetpub\CSServices\ In IIS, add a new
  website named CSServices, with the physical path pointing to the
  folder that you previously created.
- Make sure this IIS site listens    on port 1004, which will be used
  in a later stage. Create a new app    pool "CSServices", and set its
  identity to .\CSFndRuntimeUser    Depending on your IIS hostname
  binding, you may need to disable the    loop back check. Please refer
  to    http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861 for more details.

I run commands to grant admin rights as well.

But can't access following url:
http://localhost:1004/CFSolutionStorefrontSite_CatalogWebService/CatalogWebService

It is showing below error:
HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

Comment: if you access the url with the asmx at the end does it show the same error?
http://localhost:1004/CFSolutionStorefrontSite_CatalogWebService/CatalogWebService.asmx

Comment: Yes, it shows same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure:

1- the user CSFndRuntimeUser is an administrator

2- on the CSService on IIS you set Windows Authentication and Anonymous Authentication as enabled

2.1 - on the Catalog and Profile sites on IIS you set only Windows Authentication as enabled

Answer (score 0):

- Set CSSServices authentication to Anonymous
- Set CSSServices\CFSolutionStorefrontsite_CatalogWebService authentication to Anonymous
- Set CSSServices\CFSolutionStorefrontsite_ProfilesWebService authentication to Anonymous